# How does sbt reference the Project in the Build?

Tags: scala, sbt

How does sbt pick up the root project in a simple definition such as this?

```
object HelloBuild extends Build {
    lazy val root = Project(id = "hello", base = file("."))
}
```

Comment: My uninformed guess: reflection.

Comment: @AndreasFlierl seems you're right.. so simple :) http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html Add it as an answer and I'll accept it, internet points for you!

Comment: @AndreasFlierl More proof: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Build.scala#L14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My (now a bit less) uninformed guess: reflection. :)

**Edit:**
Some evidence (from the comments above):

- http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html
- https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Build.scala#L14